# Regex matching bracket in java scanner

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm wondering is it possible to match bracket with regex expression

say I need to find "[Detail]" in a text file but since "[]" is reserved it would result in selecting character "adeilt" which is not what I wanted in the first place

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(data)
s.findInLine("[Detail]")
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What is `d. findInLine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

escape reserved characters

```
\\[Detail\\]
```